How do I achieve a low poly effect on a flat plane?
I have recently got into Sculpting in Blender 4.1.0 which allows me to achieve a low poly effect where the draw sculpting tool applies contortions. However, I would like to know how I can achieve this effect on a flat plane that has not been influenced by any drawing in sculpting?
Below is an example of the low poly effect on the Sculptured segment with a smooth peripheral edge. It is the smooth peripheral edge that I would like to have a continuation of the low poly effect for the length of the face.

Please find an example of the general low poly effect I am looking to achieve:


You can either triangulate the subidivide plane (Ctrl F > Triangulate Faces), then sculpt, of sculpt with Dyntopo activated and a large Detail Size. As for the smooth transition, just use the Smooth brush? Not sure to completely understand...

if you are talking about the texture (each face seems to have a different color) I think you need to have an Image Texture that will have a kind of checker pattern, each square matching with each face of the mesh

You keep mentioning a flat plane… It’s hard to see with the camera angle, but the roof of the house in that image is not flat. It’s a trapezoid / dome kind of shape, very short but still 3-D. Anyways, if you really do want to just color a flat surface with your own shading, Gorgious is right: Use an emission shader in EEVEE with an image texture.
You might want to look into baking to help you sort of “build” the shadows you want to be applied. Baking sort of “freezes” or “saves” shading onto an image texture, see. So, you could make 3-D geometry and lighting in a such shape that has the shading you want, bake the shading to the 3-D mesh, then delete that mesh and use the texture result of the bake on the plane. Just make sure that the 3D structure you make has a UV map that has the same general shape as the 2D plane you’re going to apply the bake to afterwards, possibly matching it exactly (in the roof’s case, a square with a smaller square in the middle).

To get a floor like the one you show in the second picture, first thing right click > Shade Flat in Object mode so that you don't have any smooth shading.
For the colors, you need to use a map with a kind of checker texture and subdivide your plane as many times as necessary to match the squares, example, I have subdivided my plane 9 times to fit a 10 x 10 square texture map:

Then sculpt the plane if you want to give it bumps, and triangulate in Edit mode if you want a triangulation effect (CtrlT):

If you don't have any checker map, or don't want any, you could select the whole mesh, press U > Mark Seam, then in the UV Editor choose Pivot > Individual Origins and scale down the UV faces:

It gives this effect:

